# Java Message Expiry Checking

Tags: java

I have a simple question but a little confusing for me. Basically, I have a requirement that when a stock arrives at the particaular time, it needs to be checked that is the stock older and if it is older then the stock should be garbaged.

I have implemented the below code with unit tests. Could you please verify that it looks ok to you? Basically the current time is the threshold meaning that the application is a time ahead, so the current time has been reduced.

```
import java.util.Date;

  public class Expiry {

  public Expiry() {

  }

  public boolean hasExpired(Date currentTime, Date receivedAt) {
    boolean isExpired = false;
    System.out.println("Current Time is : " + currentTime);
    System.out.println("Received At is :" + receivedAt);
    if (currentTime.before(receivedAt)) {
        System.out.println("Keep it");
        isExpired = true;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Garbage it");
    }
    return isExpired;
    }
    }

    public class ExpiryTest {


    @Test
    public void testKeepIt() {
    Expiry expiry = new Expiry();
    Calendar receivedAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    boolean isExpired = expiry.hasExpired(currentTime.getTime(),
            receivedAt.getTime());
    assertEquals(true, isExpired);
  }

  @Test
  public void testGarbageItEqualsTo() {
    Expiry expiry = new Expiry();
    Calendar receivedAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    boolean isExpired = expiry.hasExpired(currentTime.getTime(),
            receivedAt.getTime());
    assertEquals(false, isExpired);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGarbageItAgain() {
    Expiry expiry = new Expiry();
    Calendar receivedAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    receivedAt.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);
    Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime.set(Calendar.DATE, 21);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
    currentTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    boolean isExpired = expiry.hasExpired(currentTime.getTime(),
            receivedAt.getTime());
    assertEquals(false, isExpired);
    }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not check yourself by launching your jUnitTest ?

If you know that the currentTime Date and receivedAt Date will be on the same timezone, it should be enough.

Comment: I have launched it with JUnit and it works. I just wanted someone to check whether it is right? Is there any other way to solving this problem.